# ViewController not being sized/scaled correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am starting to mess with Xcode 6 and Swift and ran into some problems with view scaling.

These screenshots will explain what my problem better:

[image: ViewController in Xcode]

[image: How the view looks on the device]

The "Auto Layout" and "Size Classes" preferences for some reason do not scale the views according to the size of the screen. Half of the table view is cut off, and the position of the top label is shifted to the right instead of being centered.

Could someone shine some light at what the problem is?

Comment: Do you running iPad layout on iPhone?

Comment: You also aren't using any constraints. You really will have to start using them, especially if you aren't using autoresizers.

Comment: try to change the size of UITableViewController to iPhone 5 fullscreen option from drop down

Comment: @LyricalPanda, shouldn't "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Size Classes" take care of the scaling for me?

Comment: @TheNotSoWise No - "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Size Classes" tells the storyboard that you are enabling auto-layout and to use that instead of auto-resizers. Auto-layout gives you a lot of power on how to scale your screens but you have to put in constraints to get it.